# Create a Virtual Box machine from a vdi clone error

Tags: virtualbox, clone

I wanted to get a clone of a colleague virtual box disk, because he had certain things in it that are time consuming to replicate.

He cloned his machine (full clone, current machine state), and sent it to me.

I made sure to upgrade my Virtual Box to exactly the same version as his, `Version 5.1.4 r110228 (Qt5.5.1)`

I tried to create a new virtual machine, loaded the vdi disk he sent me, and I got

```
Failed to open the disk image file <C:\Users\me\VirtualBox VMs\KodiakDevVMClone\KodiakDevVMClone.vdi>.

Could not get the storage format of the medium '<C:\Users\me\VirtualBox VMs\KodiakDevVMClone\KodiakDevVMClone.vdi>' (VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED).

Result Code: VBOX_E_IPRT_ERROR (0x80BB0005)
Component: MediumWrap
Interface: IMedium {4afe423b-43e0-e9d0-82e8-ceb307940dda}
Callee: IVirtualBox {0169423f-46b4-cde9-91af-1e9d5b6cd945}
Callee RC: VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80BB0001)
```

What could be the cause, and what can I do to fix it ?

Host - Windows 7, guest ubuntu-16.04.1 64bit

**Update:** trying the command from the link suggested by adampski...

```
C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox>VBoxManage.exe internalcommands repairhd -format VDI "C:\Users\me\VirtualBox VMs\KodiakDevVMClone"\KodiakDevVMClone.vdi

VBoxManage.exe: error: VDI: invalid pre-header in 'C:\Users\me\VirtualBox VMs\KodiakDevVMClone\KodiakDevVMClone.vdi'
VBoxManage.exe: error: Error code VERR_VD_IMAGE_REPAIR_IMPOSSIBLE at F:\tinderbox\win-rel\src\VBox\Storage\VDI.cpp(3004) in function int __cdecl vdiRepair(const
 char *,struct VDINTERFACE *,struct VDINTERFACE *,unsigned int)
```

Repair impossible !!!!

So how can a clone be created correctly....

Comment: Did he shutdown the VM before copying the image file? Do you have the necessary permissions for `C:\Users\me\VirtualBox VMs\KodiakDevVMClone\KodiakDevVMClone.vdi`?

Comment: @adampski yes fully shutdown - what permissions ? (I copied the disk on my system - "me" is really me, my user folder)

Comment: Depends what copy function you carried out you probably preserved the NTFS permissions (I'm assuming this is a Windows setup). Right click > properties > security. If all is well, perhaps this might help https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/10785